# Quit Option in C

Tags: c

I know this is a really silly piece of code and it's only for me to try and get my head around things... I think I've done okay, (apart from not properly indenting)

But I'm struggling with giving the user the option to quit the program using the 'Q' Character, but can't seem to get it right?

Can anybody please help..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define YEAR 2015

int main()
{
    int yearBorn, age, ageLimit,years;
    char quit = 'Q';

    ageLimit=16;

    do // The program will continue running until the user enters an age greater than 16 or presses the 'Q' character
       // to quit the program
    {        
        printf("\nPlease Enter The Year You Were Born: ");
        scanf(" %d", &yearBorn);

        age= YEAR-yearBorn;
        years=ageLimit-age;

        if (yearBorn==YEAR) //This IF statement will run if the user enters the current year!
        {
            printf("Please double check your entry as it seems ");
            printf("that you havent been born yet?");

        }
        else if (age<=ageLimit) //If the users age is less than 16 program prints the following messages
        {
            printf("\nYou are too young to play the Lottery!\n");
            printf("you have to wait %d year%s before you can play!\n\n",years,(years!=1) ? "s" : " ");

            printf("You are %d\n",age);    
        }    
    }while (years>=1);

    age = YEAR-yearBorn;    
    printf("You're old enough.. for heavens sake you are %d years old \n", age);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I indent the code for you, it could nice you take the time to do it yourself for the next question instead of mentionning 'apart from not properly indenting'

Comment: duly noted.. extremely new to coding... but will do! Many Thanks

Comment: always check the returned value from scanf() (and family) to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Comment: always wrap #define'd numbers in parens '(' and ')' to avoid certain text replacement problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
the following is one way to handle this application

notice the inclusion of error checking
notice the inclusion of a proper user prompt 
notice the method for checking of the user entered 'Q'
notice the method for exiting the application
notice that 'age', once calculated does not need to be recalculated
    when exiting program
this algorithm can fail when the year born is 16 years ago
    as it would then depend on the birth month/day compared to today
It would be a good idea to check the converted yearBorn for validity
    as a atoi() failure would result in yearBorn being 0;


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit and EXIT_FAILURE

#define YEAR      (2015)
#define AGE_LIMIT (16)
#define QUIT      'Q'

int main()
{
    int  yearBorn;
    int  age;
    int  years = 1;

    char buffer[20];




    do // The program will continue running until the user enters an age greater than 16 or presses the 'Q' character
       // to quit the program
    {
        printf("\nPlease Enter The Year You Were Born or 'Q' to quit: ");
        if( NULL == fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) )
        { // then fgets failed
            perror( "fgets for birth year failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fgets successful

        if( QUIT == buffer[0] ) {break;}

        yearBorn = atoi(buffer);

        age= YEAR-yearBorn;
        years=AGE_LIMIT-age;

        if (yearBorn==YEAR) //This IF statement will run if the user enters the current year!
        {
            printf("Please double check your entry as it seems ");
            printf("that you havent been born yet?");

        }

        else if (age<AGE_LIMIT) //If the users age is less than 16 program prints the following messages
        {
            printf("\nYou are too young to play the Lottery!\n");
            printf("you have to wait %d year%s before you can play!\n\n",years,(years!=1) ? "s" : " ");

            printf("You are %d\n",age);
        }  // end if

    }while (years>=1);

    if( years <= 0 )
    {
        printf("You're old enough.. for heavens sake you are %d years old \n", age);
    }

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: This answer has been extremely useful as the program works just how I wanted.. I'm just going to look up a few functions (atoi,fgets,sizeof,stain,&NULL) again thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For that, don't use:

```
scanf("%d", &yearBorn)
```

use instead:

```
char someString[100];
scanf("%99s", someString)
```

and then check if `someString` is "Q" (using `stricmp`). If it is not, then you can use `atoi` to convert it to a number.

Comment: Ouch! Prone to buffer overflow! Not a safe approach

Comment: Better use `scanf("%99s", someString)`.

Comment: I'd recommend getchar() to read a single character, but if you're committed to scanf(), use something like scanf("%99s", somestring); (where '99' is the size of your buffer -1 for the string terminator).

Comment: Thanks to all three above comments. I didn't thought of the overflow. Fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Just declare an `opt` variable of type `char` and add this just before the `} while (years>1);` line:

```
printf ("Press %c and ENTER to quit, or just ENTER to repeat: ", quit);
do
  opt = getchar();
while (opt!=quit && opt!='\n');
if (opt==quit)
  break;
```

To avoid executing always the last `printf`, enclose it in an `if` statement

```
if (opt!=quit)
{
    age = YEAR-yearBorn;    
    printf("You're old enough.. for heavens sake you are %d years old \n", age);
}
```

Comment: Having a slight problem in that it also prints out the last printf statement that they are old enough... then it quits?